# Uncaught (in Promise) while trying to convert a div into a downloadable image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a part of my html into a downloadable image.
For this I am using [dom2image.js](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) and [file-saver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

I followed the usage examples that they gave me, but I am having a error right after I click my button.[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

```
function generateBanner() {
    domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
    .then(function(blob) {
      console.log("blob", blob)
      debugger;
      window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
    });
}



     <article id="wrapper">
         <p>{{ title }}</p>
          <img class="logo" src="http://myurlimage.png" alt="">
          <aside class="exclusive" ng-if="exclusive"></aside>
          <aside class="off" ng-if="percentoff">
            {{ percentoff }}
          </aside>
           <div class="produtos">
             <img src="{{ produto1 }}" alt="">
              <img src="{{ produto2 }}" alt="">  
           </div>
                <aside class="valid" ng-if="valid"></aside>
                <footer>
                  {{footer}}
                </footer
              <button class="btn" id="generate" type="button" ng-click="generateBanner()">
                    <span>
                        download as img
                    </span>
                </button>
```

Comment: Try adding a `catch` like in the first example here ~ https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#usage

Comment: I did. the error is the same

Comment: just remembering, that I am running this in a localhost

Comment: I can't see it. What did you add? Also, what does your HTML look like? What triggers the `generateBanner()` function?

Comment: I suspect you have an image in your markup (class "logo") that cannot be loaded into an SVG. How are you opening the HTML page, via `http://` or `file:///`?

Comment: @Phil http://  I will edit with my html

Comment: You getting any CORS related errors around that `http://myurlimage.png` image? Any other errors at all?

Comment: @Phil none errors, except this one